# Can mysql query have 2 inner join with 2 IN clause?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 4 different mysql table,

```
SELECT node.created AS node_created, node.nid AS nid, node.title AS title 
FROM node
INNER JOIN  field_data_field_resume_education ON field_data_field_resume_education.entity_id = node.nid
INNER JOIN 
    field_data_field_resume_of_study ON 
    field_data_field_resume_of_study.entity_id =
    field_data_field_resume_education.field_resume_education_value
INNER JOIN 
    field_data_field_resume_degree_level ON 
    field_data_field_resume_degree_level.entity_id =
    field_data_field_resume_education.field_resume_education_value 
WHERE  field_data_field_resume_degree_level.field_resume_degree_level_tid  IN (4,7) 
AND  field_data_field_resume_of_study.field_resume_of_study_tid IN (18,19,21) 
and (node.status = '1') 
AND (node.type IN  ('resume_content ')) 
GROUP BY nid 
ORDER BY node_created DESC
```

Iam trying to get values from 2 different tables such that IT returns only the common values present in both, But it just returns an empty query. I have checked that both have a common nodeid.

Can we have 2 IN clause conditions in the where clause.

Please can any tell me what`s wrong with the code.

Comment: You have an extra space in `'resume_content '`

Comment: Use OR instead of AND

Comment: @juergend - I checked removing extra space, but didnt work

Comment: @Mihai - I tried using OR, But I want both the conditions to work, i.e  If table 1 has study as 12 with entity id as 25, table 2 has degree as 13 with entity id as 25,

Comment: I did not say your query will work then. It is just one error in it.

Answer (score 0):

If node.type IN  ('resume_content ') is not the issue then check othet two joins and all condition in where, one of these will be failing like join `field_data_field_resume_of_study.entity_id =    field_data_field_resume_education.field_resume_education_value` can fail.

You should execute  select * from one table
then select * from one table join another
then select * from one table join another join 3rd
then select * from one table join another join 3rd and where condition 1, you will easily cam to know where its failing...

Comment: Can u suggest me a different way by which I can add the conditions, I need "field_data_field_resume_degree_level.field_resume_degree_level_tid  IN (4,7)  AND  field_data_field_resume_of_study.field_resume_of_study_tid IN (18,19,21)"

Comment: You can include these with join conditions  like INNER JOIN 
    field_data_field_resume_of_study ON 
    field_data_field_resume_of_study.entity_id =
    field_data_field_resume_education.field_resume_education_value and field_data_field_resume_of_study.field_resume_of_study_tid IN (18,19,21)

Comment: Example Query : SELECT * FROM mySQL.user b 
 JOIN mySQL.user a ON a.user=b.user AND a.select_priv IN ('Y','N')
 JOIN mySQL.user c ON b.user=c.user AND a.Insert_priv IN ('N')

Comment: Will try what you have suggested.